How to add Authorization header to SOAP request with THTTPRIO in Delphi XE7?
I use THTTPRIO in Delphi XE7 to get data from a SOAP server. I try the request with SoapUI without a problem.
POST /ClientServices/ClientServPort.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "getUserList"
Authorization: Basic YjNm...Uo0Z1Y0cA==
Content-Length: 436
Host: eclienttest.abc.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.2)


<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:en="http:/abc.com/eUserList/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <en:getUserListRequest>
         <en:Role>AAA</en:Role>
     </en:getUserListRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

On the Delphi side, I can't add Authorization: Basic YjNm...Uo0Z1Y0cA== to the request header.  How can I do that?

Set the UserName and Password properties of the THTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.  They will be combined and base64-encoded into the Authorization header when the HTTP request is created.
